# How do you update a driver after a fresh CentOS installation?

Tags: centos, installation, redhat, rpm, centos5

I've been a long time Debian user but now I'm working with Red Hat and I'm a bit lost. I just installed a fresh install of CentOS 5.5 on a new Dell server. Dell provides a current Red Hat 5.5 driver for mpt2sas. How do I install this driver?

The Dell instructions are not that helpful. They explain an RPM Install and a DKMS Install - what's the difference between the two?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the RPM would install the DKMS really..

Unpack the driver package : `tar -xvzf <driver_package>`

Then CD into the dir it was extracted to and `rpm -Uvh *.rpm`

And all will be well :)

Answer (score 0):

RPM is the basic package management system.  DKMS is Dynamic Kernel Module Support.  The two are not mutually exclusive, you can have an RPM of a DKMS module.

If you have a straight RPM of a driver, it will have to match the specific version of the kernel you are running.  What DKMS allows you to do, is install a module that will automatically be rebuilt if the kernel changes.  So I would recommend following the instructions for that.